# This is only a subspace if $b=0$ - Axler - LADR p13

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory

I have written here in Axler - Linear Algebra Done Right, page $13$.

> If $b\in \mathbb{F}$, then $\{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\in \mathbb{F}^4: x_3 = 5x_4 + b\}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{F}^4$ if and only if $b=0$

I am not sure what this is getting at. Why is this the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A subspace must contain the zero vector.

Comment: Oh my, I feel very silly now.

Comment: Since $(0,0,0,0)$ must be an element, we have $(0,0,b,0)$ xD

Comment: @Committingtoachallenge, but you have committed to the challenge right?

Comment: @Nameless But you have a name?

Comment: @lhf I am confused, are the components of the tuple scalars or vectors?